# My value checker function needs to return both a boolean and a message

Tags: java, error-handling

I have a value checking function, something much like a credit card number checking function, that is passed in a string, and needs to check that the value is of the right format.

If it's the right format it needs to return true.

If it's not the right format it needs to return false, and also tell us what's wrong with the value.

The question is, what's the nicest way to achieve this?

Here's a few solutions:

**1. Use integer/enum return codes to signify meanings:**

```
String[] returnCodeLookup = 
[
"Value contains wrong number of characters, should contain 10 characters",
"Value should end with 1", 
"Value should be a multiple of 3"
]

private int valueChecker(String value)
{
    /*check value*/
    return returnCode;
}

rc = checkValue(valueToBeChecked);
if rc == 0
{
    /*continue as normal*/
}
else
{
    print("Invalid value format: ") + returnCodeLookup[rc];
}
```

I don't like this solution as it it requires implementation on the caller side of things.

**2. Create a returnCode class**

```
Class ReturnCode()
{
    private boolean success;
    private String message;

    public boolean getSuccess()
    {
        return this.success;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return this.message; 
    }
}

private ReturnCode valueChecker(String value)
{
    /*check value*/
    return returnCode;
}

rc = checkValue(valueToBeChecked);
if rc.getSuccess()
{
    /*continue as normal*/
}
else
{
    print("Invalid value format: ") + rc.getMessage();
}
```

This solution is tidy, but it seems like overkill/reinventing the wheel.

**3. Use exceptions.**

```
private boolean valueChecker(String value)
{
    if int(value)%3 != 0 throw InvalidFormatException("Value should be a multiple of 3";
    /*etc*/
    return True;
}

try {
rc = checkValue(valueToBeChecked);
}

catch (InvalidFormatException e)
{
     print e.toString();
}
```

I'm tempted to use this solution, but I'm told that you shouldn't use exceptions for business logic.

Comment: '[..] check that the value is of the right format.' Shouldn't the name be _FormatChecker_, then?

Comment: The true/false result seems redundant.  Could it simply return an empty or null String to indicate success?  That's worked for UNIX for about 50 years.  :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a more complex return object that encapsulates both concerns. Example:

```
public interface IValidationResult {
  boolean isSuccess();
  String getMessage();
}
```

This has several advantages:

1. Returns multiple related pieces of data in one object.
2. Room for expansion if you need to add additional data in the future.
3. No reliance on temporal coupling: you can validate multiple inputs and they do not clobber the message as in the other answer. You can check messages in any order, across threads even.

I have actually used this specific design before, in applications where a validation may be more than simply true or false. Perhaps a detailed message is necessary, or only part of the input is invalid (e.g. a form with ten elements might only have one or two invalid fields). Using this design, you can easily accommodate those requirements.

Comment: I must admit this solution is better than mine. Mine is not threadsafe.

Comment: @user61852 While this is a high level overview of an interface for a result object, I think the goal here is that the validation code would be its own object containing no state. That would make it immutable, which has many benefits that we talk about over and over on this site.

Comment: Why is an interface necessary?

Comment: @dwjohnston an interface is not necessary, but it is a good idea. Inheritance is a very strong type of coupling that should only be used when necessary.

Comment: Alternately, you can simplify further. Success is not interesting, so declare a constant `IValidationResult.SUCCESS` that returns an empty error message. Then your logic looks like `if (result != SUCCESS) { doStuff(result.getMessage()); }`

Comment: @Morgen I would program to the interface, not the instance. Using `(!result.isSuccess()) { doStuff(result.getMessage()); }` is guaranteed to work regardless of the instance returned, and is just about as verbose.

Comment: @Snowman There are advantages either way. The primary benefit of providing a canonical success object with the interface is that, if the majority of the validations are expected to succeed, fewer object instantiations are required - at the cost of a single, long-lived object. This also makes returning success easier. `return SUCCESS;` is much simpler than `return new IValidationResult() { ... implement un-interesting success boilerplate here ... };`. It's also flexible, `(!result.isSuccess())` still works.

Comment: @Snowman In this case you are returning data. There is no need for behavior. Abstraction is a tool; it need not be used everywhere.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret behavior? This interface represents a simple container: a boolean and a string. It does not actually _do_ anything.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above, use a ValueChecker class

First an interface to give you flexibility:

```
public interface IValueChecker {
    public boolean checkValue(String value);
    public String getLastMessage();
}
```

---

Then implement as many valuecheckers as you need:

```
public class MyVeryEspecificValueChecker implements IValueChecker {
    private String lastMessage="";
    @Override
    public boolean checkValue(String value) {
        boolean valid=false;
        // perform check, updates "valid" and "lastMessage"
        return valid;
    }
    @Override
    public String getLastMessage() {
        return lastMessage;
    }
}
```

---

Sample client code:

```
public class TestValueChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String valueToCheck="213123-YUYAS-27163-10";
        IValueChecker vc = new MyVeryEspecificValueChecker();
        vc.checkValue(valueToCheck);
        System.out.println(vc.getLastMessage());
    }
}
```

---

It has the advantage that you can have many different value checkers.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the value checker keeping state, without having a way to see the last value checked.

Answer (score 1):

My answer extends @Snowman's approach. Basically, every validation, every business rule and every business-logic should be able to result in some response -- at least, in web applications. This response, in turn, is displayed to a caller. This brought me to the following interface (it's php, but the question is language-agnostic in nature):

```
interface Action
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @throws RuntimeException
     * @return Response
     */
    public function act(Request $request);
}
```

Creating switch operator acting like a expression, not like statement, leads to application service looking like that:

```
class MyApplicationService implements Action
{
    private $dataStorage;

    public function __construct(UserDataStorage $dataStorage)
    {
        $this->dataStorage = $dataStorage;
    }

    public function act(Request $request)
    {
        return
            (new _SwitchTrue(
                new _Case(
                    new EmailIsInvalid(),
                    new EmailIsInvalidResponse()
                ),
                new _Case(
                    new PasswordIsInvalid(),
                    new PasswordIsInvalidResponse()
                ),
                new _Case(
                    new EmailAlreadyRegistered($this->dataStorage),
                    new EmailAlreadyRegisteredResponse()
                ),
                new _Default(
                    new class implements Action
                    {
                        public function act(Request $request)
                        {
                            // business logic goes here

                            return new UserRegisteredResponse();
                        }
                    }
                )
            ))
                ->act($request)
            ;
    }
}
```